# How to access or update the component class variable in other component class angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have body, for home page I want to apply 'home' class and 'other' for rest of the page. This body is defined in index.html.

Now appcomponent has public variable 'homePage = true' for Index.html. For other page I want to access this variable and set the 'homePage = false'.

Comment: <body class="home" [ngClass] = "{'home':homePage, 'other':!homePage}">  body is defined like this

Answer (score 0):

In your app component you can do following to check your URL and set `homePage` variable if you are using Angular RC4:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector  : 'app'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public homePage: Boolean    = true;
  private router: Router;

  constructor(router: Router){
    this.router         = router;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((events) => {
      if (events instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (events.url === '/' || events.url === '/home') {
          this.homePage = true;
        } else {
          this.homePage = false;
        }
      }
    });
    this.homePage = (this.router.url === '/' || this.router.url === '/home') ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Also you have to change your body tag to : `<body [ngClass] = "{'home':homePage, 'other':!homePage}">`

Comment: this.router.events throwing an error... "angular2.dev.js:23083 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined in [null]"

Comment: i have used it in Angular RC4 and is working fine. are you using the Angular RC4 ?

Comment: How can I find it.. I think RC2

Comment: you need to check version in your package.json file.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  }

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get rid of class="home"...

```
<body [ngClass]="{home: homePage, other: !homePage}">
```

Although, I'm not sure how you can have angular 2 directives on the body tag.. You should have a tag inside the body that is the primary component (ie: the one you bootstrapped angular with) so anything outside of that wouldn't be enhanced with angular 2's awesomesauce.